# woocommerce/sensei dynamic/changeable button in secondary menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I would like to add a button to my secondary menu which points to a 'my account' page and the text on the button should display 'my account' if the user is logged in.

If the user is logged out, they would see a button that says 'register' and points to a login page.

Anyone know if this is possible?

I think i am close but i am unsure if it's possible:

This is in my child theme's functions.php:

```
    function storefront_secondary_navigation() {
        if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) {
            ?>
            <nav class="secondary-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Secondary Navigation', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <p>wat is deze</p>
                <?php


                        if( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
                        wp_nav_menu(
                                array(
                                    'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
                                    'fallback_cb'       => '',

                                )

                            );

                        }
                        else{
                        wp_nav_menu(
                                array(
                                    'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
                                    'fallback_cb'       => '',

                                )

                            );

                        }
echo "menu locations";
$hoi = get_nav_menu_locations();
var_dump($hoi);
//outputs an array with 3 objects: 'primary', 'secondary', and 'handheld'.
                ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A pure CSS solution:

In Wordpress, the `<body>` element has the class `logged-in` if a user is logged in. So you can use this to hide the right button:

Add this to your `style.css`:

```
#menu-item-8071 {
    display: none;
}

body.logged-in #menu-item-8071 {
    display: block;
}

body.logged-in #menu-item-8011 {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Instead of using menu-items ids as css selector, you can add your own css classes to your buttons. First you have to enable "CSS Classes" in the Screen Options (at top of the menu editor page). Now you can enter additional css classes for each menu item.

e.g.:

- `show-if-logged-in` for the first button
- `hide-if-logged-in` for the second button

So you can use this css code:

```
.show-if-logged-in {
    display: none;
}

body.logged-in show-if-logged-in {
    display: block;
}

body.logged-in .hide-if-logged-in {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah i didnt know that, thats a pretty simplistic solution! Thanks i think i'll use this one instead of mine. (unless i want to do animations or other conditional checks).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Maybe you like the second solution :)

Comment: Yeah cool thanks that works as well, now i can link future elements to this class so i dont need duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it and it works. I made 2 seperate items in the secondary menu via the wordpress menu editor. Then i created an action hook where it checks if the user is logged in or out and then hides the button (with the corresponding link that was setup in the menus editor) accordingly.

The drawback of this is that it is not easily maintainable, it requires the developer to get the element by ID so if someone changes the menu settings, it would probably get a different ID and thus be fixed manually each time.

```
function modify_secondary_menu_buttons() {                  
        if( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery("#menu-item-8071").css("display", "none");
            </script>'; 
            return;

        }
        else{
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            // Document ready
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("You are logged in");

                jQuery("#menu-item-8011").css("display", "none");

            });
            </script>';         
        }           
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'modify_secondary_menu_buttons' );
```